# CSV output only takes the first set of the dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

i am wanting to convert my list dictionaries to CSV but the output only seems to be taking the first set of data.

this is my current code:

```
import csv

order = {'company_name': 'FRIENDS',  'delivery_timeslot': '18-21', 'latitude': '1.37315509207642000000', 'longitude': '103.76570152476201000000', 'status': 'pending', 'date': '2019-12-06', 'region': 'WEST'}
{'company_name': 'FLOWERS', 'delivery_timeslot': '18-21', 'latitude': '1.28821802835873000000', 'longitude': '103.84569230314800000000', 'status': 'pending', 'date': '2019-11-29', 'region': 'CENTRAL'}
{'company_name': 'SUNSHINE',  'delivery_timeslot': '18-21', 'latitude': '1.37414901860683000000', 'longitude': '103.94353973518100000000', 'status': 'pending', 'date': '2019-11-08', 'region': 'EAST'}
{'company_name': 'CLOUDS', 'delivery_timeslot': '18-21', 'latitude': '1.39663901543996000000', 'longitude': '103.81937713764700000000', 'status': 'pending', 'date': '2019-10-25', 'region': 'NORTH'}
{'company_name': 'SUN',  'delivery_timeslot': '10-13', 'latitude': '1.23123112888888800000', 'longitude': '1.00000000000008100000', 'status': 'pending', 'date': '2019-10-18', 'region': 'NORTH'}

csv_file = "test.csv"
csv_columns = order.keys()
try:
    with open(csv_file, 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns)
        writer.writeheader()
        for i in order:
            writer.writerow(order)
except IOError:
    print("I/O error")
```

this is my output:

```
company_name,delivery_timeslot,latitude,longitude,status,date,region

FRIENDS,18-21,1.37315509207642000000,103.76570152476201000000,pending,2019-12-06,WEST

FRIENDS,18-21,1.37315509207642000000,103.76570152476201000000,pending,2019-12-06,WEST

FRIENDS,18-21,1.37315509207642000000,103.76570152476201000000,pending,2019-12-06,WEST

FRIENDS,18-21,1.37315509207642000000,103.76570152476201000000,pending,2019-12-06,WEST

FRIENDS,18-21,1.37315509207642000000,103.76570152476201000000,pending,2019-12-06,WEST

FRIENDS,18-21,1.37315509207642000000,103.76570152476201000000,pending,2019-12-06,WEST

FRIENDS,18-21,1.37315509207642000000,103.76570152476201000000,pending,2019-12-06,WEST
```

how do i resolve this? do i need to do some loop function in order for it to work?

Comment: `order` IS only the first set of data.  Those next four lines are individual statements that create a dictionary and then discard it.  You need square brackets around the whole thing to make a list of your dictionaries.

Comment: shouldn't it be ```writer.writerow(i)``` instead of ```writer.writerow(order)```

Comment: @jasonharper but what if I don't want to add those square brackets? is there any way around that?

Comment: To use _a list of dictionarys_ you need the brackets around them - it is how lists are defined: `[1,2,3,4,5]` or `[{1:11,2:22,3:33},{4:44,5:55}]`

Comment: If you don't want to use those square brackets: enjoy your non-working program, I guess.

Comment: `neworder = list(order)

csv_file = "data.csv"
csv_columns = neworder.keys()
try:
    with open(csv_file, 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns)
        writer.writeheader()
        for i in neworder:
            writer.writerow(neworder)
except IOError:
    print("I/O error")`

Comment: @PatrickArtner I have tried to convert into a list but it still doesn't work. the error being `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'`

Comment: @jasonharper I have tried to convert it to a list but the code still doesn't work. `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'` any idea as to why?

Answer (score 0):

`order` is just **one** dictionary. The other dictionaries are *declared* but not stored inside a variable - the immediately go *POOF* and are gone.

Your csv contains `order`  exacly as many times as `order` has got keys, because:

> ```
>        for i in order:               # i is any key in order-dict after another
>            writer.writerow(order)    # not doing anything with the key, so simply
>                                        # add the same single dict over and over
> ```

---

You need to create a LIST of dictionaries:

```
import csv

order = [ {'company_name': 'FRIENDS',  'delivery_timeslot': '18-21', 
           'latitude': '1.37315509207642000000', 'longitude': '103.76570152476201000000', 
           'status': 'pending', 'date': '2019-12-06', 'region': 'WEST'}, # end  1st item

          {'company_name': 'FLOWERS', 'delivery_timeslot': '18-21', 
           'latitude': '1.28821802835873000000', 'longitude': '103.84569230314800000000', 
           'status': 'pending', 'date': '2019-11-29', 'region': 'CENTRAL'}, # end 2nd item

          {'company_name': 'SUNSHINE',  'delivery_timeslot': '18-21', 
           'latitude': '1.37414901860683000000', 'longitude': '103.94353973518100000000', 
           'status': 'pending', 'date': '2019-11-08', 'region': 'EAST'}, # ...

          {'company_name': 'CLOUDS', 'delivery_timeslot': '18-21', 
           'latitude': '1.39663901543996000000', 'longitude': '103.81937713764700000000', 
           'status': 'pending', 'date': '2019-10-25', 'region': 'NORTH'}, # ...

          {'company_name': 'SUN',  'delivery_timeslot': '10-13', 
           'latitude': '1.23123112888888800000', 'longitude': '1.00000000000008100000', 
           'status': 'pending', 'date': '2019-10-18', 'region': 'NORTH'} ] # end of list

csv_file = "test.csv"
csv_columns = order[0].keys()  # use the first dictionary as template for columns
try:
    with open(csv_file, 'w') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=csv_columns)
        writer.writeheader()
        for dictionary in order:
            writer.writerow(dictionary)
except IOError:
    print("I/O error")
```

Test:

```
with open(csv_file) as f:
    print(f.read())
```

Output:

```
company_name,delivery_timeslot,latitude,longitude,status,date,region
FRIENDS,18-21,1.37315509207642000000,103.76570152476201000000,pending,2019-12-06,WEST
FLOWERS,18-21,1.28821802835873000000,103.84569230314800000000,pending,2019-11-29,CENTRAL
SUNSHINE,18-21,1.37414901860683000000,103.94353973518100000000,pending,2019-11-08,EAST
CLOUDS,18-21,1.39663901543996000000,103.81937713764700000000,pending,2019-10-25,NORTH
SUN,10-13,1.23123112888888800000,1.00000000000008100000,pending,2019-10-18,NORTH
```

Comment: how do i convert my current dictionaries to a list of dictionaries instead of inputting my own [ ] ?

 i tried `neworder = list(order)` but it only gives me the keys (column names) 
`['company_name', 'delivery_address', 'delivery_timeslot', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'status', 'date', 'region']`

Comment: @Yuna You add `[` before, add `,` between and add `]` after them in your source code. Or you create an empty list and append them one by one. See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#data-structures